# Creating multidimensional array while reading a file - Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I'm totally new to Perl, and I've been assigned some task... I have to read a tab separated file, and then do some operations with the data in a DB. The .tsv file is like this:

ID      Name     Date

155     Pedro    1988-05-05

522     Mengano  2002-08-02

So far I thought that creating a multidimensional array with the data of the file will be a good solution to handle this data later. So I read the file line by line, skip the item title columns and save the values in an array. However, I'm having difficulties creating this multidimensional array... this is what I've done so far:

```
#Read file from path
my @array;
my $fh = path($filename)->openr_utf8;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    # skip comments and blank lines and title line
    next if $line =~ /^\#/ || $line =~ /^\s*$/ || $line =~ /^\+/ || $line =~ /ID/;
    #split each line into array
    my @aux_line = split(/\s+/, $line);
    push @array, @{ $aux_line };
    }
```

Obviously, last line is not working... how could be done to create an array of arrays this way? I'm little bit lost with references... And somebody can think of a better way to store this data we read from file? Thank you!

Comment: `push @array, \@$aux_line;`

Comment: I assume this question was answered many times before. Use `Text::CSV` or `Text::CSV::Slurp`. It can use the first line as field names, creates an array of hashes with field names as key and is nearly ready for inserting into a database via `DBIx::Class` if the field names match the column names of the DB.

Comment: I was thinking first of the solution with hash, but isn't it more difficult to manage in this way @HelmutWollmersdorfer? Because I have the following conditions when I read the file and connect to db:

- If there already exists record in DB with given ID, that record is updated with information from file and Update_timestamp is set to system current timestamp.
- If new record is detected in file, new record is created in DB with attributes from file and Update_timestamp is set to system current timestamp.

Comment: - If any update is detected, record in DB is updated and Update_timestamp is set to system current timestamp.
- If record does not exist in the file, no action is taken.

That's why I thought It would be better to operate with arrays instead of hashes, cause it would be easier to compare.

Comment: Another option is to read your data with SQL using [`DBD::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3A%3ACSV).

Comment: @reinierpost just changing this for a " "? csv_sep_char     => ","

Comment: @ArtanisAce With `DBIx::Class` you can use `$schema->resultset('MyTable')->update_or_create($hashref_of_csv_record);` Should fit in your case where you have the IDs in the TSV records.

Comment: thanks @HelmutWollmersdorfer for the help!! My problem is that I'm too new to Perl, and this DBIx::Class looks complex to work with... anyway my biggest concern is comparing the data of .tsv file to the DB records, once I have hash refs for both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `use strict` and `use warnings`. That would instantly alert you about that your wrong way to get array reference tries to access completely different variable (Perl allows variable of different types have same names).

After that just change your last line to:

```
push @array, \@aux_line;
```

Comment: Oh was trying some stuff but not this! Now I think got the point; passing a reference don't pass any value but just the memory location... that's why when you use 'push' the values of '@array_line' don't get pushed to '@array' right? Thank you very much Oleg!

Comment: Pretty much so. On top level you have array filled with references to other arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with `map`:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @stuff = map {[split]} <$fh>;
print Dumper \@stuff;
```

(with maybe a grep to skip comments)

But it may suit your use case better to use an array of hashes :

```
my @stuff ;
chomp(my @header = split ' ', <$fh>);
while ( <$fh>)  {
    my %this_row;
    @this_row{@header} = split;
    push ( @stuff, \%this_row) ;
}
```

Comment: This hash-based solution is almost certainly superior in this case.